# Displaying updated value from Angular service

Tags: angular

I have a header component that will be used in many modules within my project. It will display the title of the current view.

In the current page component (client-list-component.ts), I'm calling a service's changeTitle method to change the title. I confirmed via a breakpoint in VS Code that the method is getting the new value, but the new value is not shown in page-header.component.html. Instead, I see the default title that is set in the service ("No Title Set").

The PageHeaderComponent is part of a shared module.

I'm using Angular 5.

client-list-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PageHeaderService } from "../../shared/page-header/page-header.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'client-list',
  templateUrl: './client-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-list.component.scss']
})
export class ClientListComponent implements OnInit {

  public hasClients = false;
  public title: string;

  constructor(private data: PageHeaderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.changeTitle("Clients")
  }
}
```

page-header.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class PageHeaderService {

  private titleSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("No Title Set");
  currentTitle = this.titleSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeTitle(title: string) {
    this.titleSource.next(title)
  }

}
```

page-header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PageHeaderService } from "./page-header.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-header',
  templateUrl: './page-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-header.component.scss'],
  providers: [PageHeaderService]
})
export class PageHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public showSearch = false;
  public search: string;
  public title;

  constructor(private data: PageHeaderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentTitle.subscribe(title => this.title = title);
  }

}
```

page-header.component.html

```
<header>
    <div fxFlex fxFlexLayoutAlign="center">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>   
        </div>  
    </div>
</header>
```

shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';

import { PageHeaderService } from './page-header/page-header.service';
import { PageHeaderComponent } from './page-header/page-header.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    PageHeaderComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    CommonModule,
    PageHeaderComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    PageHeaderService
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: Is your `ClientListComponent` declared inside a lazy-loaded module?

Comment: I think so, because it's included as a child in an unnamed router-outlet.

Comment: "I confirmed via a breakpoint in VS Code that the method is getting the new value...". Which method? Are you sure that there is only one provider for the service? Also, for a test, you can try setting the title in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.

Comment: The thing is your `PageHeaderService` probably isn't a singleton (was instantiated more than once) so the instance of  the service you're injecting in both components is different, can you do a quick `console.log` in the constructor of the service? how many logs are you getting?

Comment: The value doesn't update when this.data.changeTitle("Projects") is called inside ngAfterViewInit. The method I'm referring to is changeTitle in the service. This method is getting the new value.

Comment: When I add a console log in PageHeaderService's constructor, I see two console logs.

Comment: And that's because the service is not a singleton, checkout the dependency injection guide from the angular docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try providing the `PageHeaderService` in the *module* instead of the header component.

If you provide the service in the page header component, an instance of the `PageHeaderService` will be created for ***every*** instance of the component, which probably isn't something you want here.

Comment: PageHeaderService is used in the component's constructor, so I don't think I can remove it from the component.

Comment: I'm asking you to remove line `providers: [PageHeaderService]` from component and place it in the module.

Comment: @depiction alongside removing `providers: [PageHeaderService]` from your `page-header.component.ts` I would also move the `providers: [PageHeaderService]` from your `SharedModule` to your `AppModule`(or whatever your core module is)

Comment: Moving `providers: [PageHeaderService]` from the shared module to the app module solved the problem. I'm not sure why that made a difference. Since the shared module was imported into app module, it should have been available.

Answer (score 0):

When we use multi module on angular service are noy singleton. Each module create an instance of this service , ref:
 https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#singleton-services

Answer (score 0):

When we use multi module on angular service are noy singleton. Each module create an instance of this service , ref https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#singleton-services